# Update Relate Table With a lot of Records

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my issue.

I have a table called Propects, that has an ID for each record.
Then I have a table called Prospect Lists, where each record also has an ID.
The last table is the relate table call Prospects_lists_Prospects, where I need to assign/relate the Prospect ID to the correct Prospect List ID.
My problem is I have about 60,000 records in the Prospects table to assign to one list ID from the Prospect List table. I am using phpmyadmin as well. Is there a way to do this query without too much difficulty?

Thank you. I appreciate any help in advanced.

Comment: It isn't clear wich table you want to update which what data. Can you post your table definitions and clarify what it is that you want?

Comment: How do the two tables relate ? As long as this relation is not clear, you cannot find the solution.

Comment: Sorry. So I have one table, Prospects, that has the Prospect ID. I have another table, Prospect_Lists, that have the Prospect List ID. I then have a relate table, called Prospect_Lists_prospects, that relates the Prospect ID to the Prospect List ID. So I am updating the Prospects_List_Prospects table with all the Prospect IDs and the corresponding Propect List ID.

Comment: How do you know the ProspectID matches the ProspectLsitID?

Comment: I have to set that in the relate table. So I choose the ProspectListID to relate to the ProspectID. I must be explaining this way wrong because it's a simple relate/join table lol.

Comment: Look, you are telling us that you need to insert data on the table that relates the prospects with the lists, but you are basically asking us to **guess** how to assign a prospect with a prospect list

Comment: Ok, I see where I am going wrong here. Sorry about the confusion. So I need to take every ProspectID from the Prospect table and put them into the relate table. I know what List ID to relate them to from the ProspectList table. I just have 60,000 Prospect ID's to relate to one List ID, but it has to be done in the relate table.

Comment: @dkeeper09 I edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: Sorry i don´t understand. You have a M to M relation and the Prospects_lists_Prospects table is the composed table? and you want to save the relationship in this table just with one consult?

Answer (score 0):

Try sometihng like

```
INSERT INTO Prospects_Lists_Prospects (ProspectID, ProspectListsID)
VALUES(SELECT p.id, pl.ID FROM prospects As p INNER JOIN ProspectsLIsts aS pl ON *what they relate/compare on*
```

Taking what you said:

```
INSERT INTO Prospects_Lists_Prospects (ProspectID, ProspectListsID)
VALUES((SELECT prospectID FROM prospects), (Select ProspecListsID From ProspectsLists WHERE *Whaveter Criteria*) Or you could just put the number.
```